# open sets in a Banach space are locally connected

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a proof of the following theorem in operator algebra and I don't understand the first sentence:

[image]

Would anybody show me why the following statement is true?

> Let $X$ be a connected topological space and $U$ an open subset of $X$. Then $U$ is locally connected.

---

[updated:]
Thanks to Sarah's comment, I should have asked the following statement instead

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $U$ an open subset of $X$. Then $U$ is locally connected.

Anyway, what really confuses me is why the underlined sentence in the quoted proof is true.

Comment: All you must show is for any $x\in U$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that there is an open connected set containing $x$ but contained in $V$, i.e. $x\in C \subset V$ for some open connected set $C$. It easily follows from the fact that the whole space is connected.

Comment: @Neel OH!  crap...can you refer me to such a space? I need to do some review it seems...

Comment: @ LoveTooNap29 An example of such a space is infinite broom ........ you might consult munkres toplogy

Comment: @Jack You should say that let $X$ be a Banach space (as the proof intended) or a Metric space since it isn't true in general topological spaces

Comment: @ LoveTooNap29 sorry I was wrong there exits path connected but nowhere locally path connected space

Comment: @SarahPalinsAnger: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your revised question, note the following:

- The open balls are a basis for the norm topology on a Banach space.  So if $U$ is open, then for every $x \in U$ there is a ball $B(x,r)$ contained in $U$.
- Open balls in a normed space are path connected, hence connected.  Indeed, they are convex; given $y,z$ in a ball $B(x,r)$, the straight line segment $\gamma(t) = (1-t)y + tz$ is a continuous path joining $y$ to $z$ which is contained in $B(x,r)$ (use the triangle inequality).

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Consider a space $X$that is connected but not locally connected(example: infinite broom space). Then take $U=X$ and see the contradiction.

PS: Metric space condition would not suffice as infinite broom is subspace of plane.

Comment: The subspace $(\;\{0\}\times [-1,1]\;)\cup \{(x,\sin 1/x :x\in (0,1]\}$ of the real plane is  a compact   Hausdorff space which is connected (but not path-connected) and not locally connected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good to know that in general the statement is not true.

Comment: You are welcome! :)